# opencv draw circle tangent line from a point

Tags: c++, opencv, math, geometry

c++ project with opencv mathematical problem with drawing circle tangential points.

I'm deploying a project with c++ opencv that i have to display tangential lines on a circle from specific point which is mentioned by opencv mouse callback function. so i get the location of mouse point on screen by a point variable inside callback function like :

```
Point2f location;
location.x = x;
location.y = y;
```

now i need a function that draw tangential lines with example radius = 4 by **opencv** !!
something like this :
[circle tangential points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPP4T.png)
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case, first you have to declare a function that calculate tangential points on a sample circle and then use specific points in order to draw line matrixs with opencv.
so let's try with this function :

```
vector <double> Coverage::tangentCircle (const Point2f &mouse, const Point2f &center, double radius) {

vector <double> points (4,0);

// Line between point mouse and center
double directLine = sqrt(pow((mouse.x - center.x), 2) + pow((mouse.y - center.y), 2));

// angle of point mouse and center
double directAngle = pointAngle(mouse, center);

// angle between radius and directLine
double theta = acos(radius / directLine);

// direction angle of point tangent 1 and center
double d1 = directAngle + theta;

// direction angle of point tangent 2 and center
double d2 = directAngle - theta;

points[0] = (int)(center.x + radius * cos(d1));
points[1] = (int)(center.y + radius * sin(d1));

points[2] = (int)(center.x + radius * cos(d2));
points[3] = (int)(center.y + radius * sin(d2));

return points;
}
```

data recursion of this function is vector that contains our tangential points.
there are 3 parameters in entry section which are mouse point(x,y) and circle(x,y) and specific radius that we need.
distance formula between mouse and center calculate with Euclidean way.
i comment every part of function to make it undestandable.

after return tangential points, you can use circle line function of opencv to draw results :

```
line(screen, mouse, Point(points[0], points[1]), Scalar(100, 100, 100), 2, 8, 0);
line(screen, mouse, Point(points[2], points[3]), Scalar(100, 100, 100), 2, 8, 0);
```

Hope to be useful

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In Figure, **C** is center of your circle, **P** is clicked point, and **T** is the point you want to know.

- Triangle PCT is similar to Triangle PCK.
- The length of all 3 edges of PCT are known (one is radius and other two can be calculated).

So, you can calculate the position **K**, and then, finally, you can calculate the position **T**.

---

This is sample implementation.
Variable names **C**, **P**, **T**, **K**, and r are intentionally be the same as in the figure.

```cpp
namespace
{
    const std::string WndName = "Wnd";

    //Circle Definition
    const cv::Vec2d C{ 160, 120 };  //center
    const double r = 50;    //radius
    const double Sq_r = r*r;

    inline void DrawTheCircle( cv::Mat &ImgBuffer )
    {   cv::circle( ImgBuffer, cv::Point(C), cvRound(r), cv::Scalar(0,0,255) ); }

    //Implementation.
    //Store the calculated 2 point to the array T and returns true, if succeeded.
    //Else, returns false.
    bool CalculationImpl( const cv::Vec2d &P, cv::Vec2d (&T)[2] )
    {
        cv::Vec2d P_ = P - C;
        double SqNorm_P_ = P_(0)*P_(0) + P_(1)*P_(1);
        if( SqNorm_P_ <= Sq_r )return false;

        double SqNorm_PT = SqNorm_P_ - Sq_r;
        double Norm_PT = sqrt( SqNorm_PT );

        cv::Vec2d K_dir_Vec[2] = {  cv::Vec2d{ -P_(1), P_(0) }, cv::Vec2d{ P_(1), -P_(0) }  };
        for( int i=0; i<2; ++i )
        {
            cv::Vec2d K = K_dir_Vec[i] * r/Norm_PT;
            T[i] = P + (K-P_) * SqNorm_PT/SqNorm_P_;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Mouse Callback
    void OnMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata )
    {
        if( event != cv::EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON )return;

        cv::Mat &ImgBuff = *( (cv::Mat*)userdata );
        ImgBuff = 0;
        DrawTheCircle( ImgBuff );
        cv::drawMarker( ImgBuff, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Scalar(0,255,255), cv::MarkerTypes::MARKER_CROSS, 8 );

        cv::Vec2d T[2];
        if( CalculationImpl( cv::Vec2d(x,y), T ) )
        {
            for( const auto &t : T )
            {
                cv::drawMarker( ImgBuff, cv::Point(t), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), cv::MarkerTypes::MARKER_TILTED_CROSS, 8 );
                cv::line( ImgBuff, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Point(t), cv::Scalar(0,192,0) );
            }
        }
        cv::imshow( WndName, ImgBuff );
    }
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat ImgBuffer = cv::Mat::zeros( 240,320, CV_8UC3 );
    DrawTheCircle( ImgBuffer );
    cv::imshow( WndName, ImgBuffer );
    cv::setMouseCallback( WndName, OnMouse, &ImgBuffer );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Result samples(Unnecessary margin regions has been trimmed by hand):
[image]

---

If we think about the problem on the coordinate system just like the figure, the story becomes easier.
In other words, we only need to solve the problem in the world where **C**=(0,0), r=1, **P** = (0,v).

Simultaneous equation to solve becomes to:

- DotProdct(**P**, **T**) = 1
- |**T**| = 1

We can solve **T** straightforwardly.
Of cause, finally, convert the **T** to original coordinate system.

Comment: I'm not English native, and so I'm a little worried whether the word "is similar to" is correct in English.
I want to say the relationship between 2 triangles as "shape is same, difference is only size".